# iPad Viewport issue

Tags: wordpress, ipad

I am using the following viewport code and it isn't working for my WordPress website:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width;initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

When the website is viewed in the iPad in portrait mode, it isn't scaling right. There are large sections of the body background missing instead of spanning all the way ascross and top to bottom.

Here is the URL of the website in question:
http://themobmuseum.org

Any help would be appreciate. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are using for viewport is incorrect.

This is the correct syntax:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />`

This is the incorrect syntax:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;" />`

Reference:
http://alxgbsn.co.uk/2011/11/23/make-sure-to-use-correct-meta-viewport-syntax/